# Make an Embedded field to be not updatable in JPA

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I would like to make the @Embedded field "foo" in my entity to be NOT updatable in JPA 2.0

```
    @Entity
    public class Entity {

      @Id
      @SequenceGenerator(name = "Seq", sequenceName = "SEQ", allocationSize = 10)
      @GeneratedValue(generator = "Seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
      String id;

      @Embedded
      private FooEmbeddable foo;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public class FooEmbedable{

       String fooString;
       String barString;
    }
```

If instead of @Embeddable i had another entity I could use the updatable=false property of the @Column annotation, but there is not such attribute in @Embedded

I have found an example that the @Column(updatable=false) annotation was used directly on the fields of the Embeddable. i.e.

```
    @Embeddable
    public class FooEmbedable{
       @Column(updatable=false)
       String fooString;

       @Column(updatable=false)
       String barString;
    }
```

..but what happens if I use FooEmbedable to also another table where i want it to be updatable?

Do i miss something?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

updatable=false is more for when you have multiple mappings that map the same column and you want to designate one as the owner.

If you just don't want to update something, then just don't change it in your application (or even don't add set methods for it).